# The clean URL test failed. (ubuntu14.04 lts + virtualmin + Apache/2.4.7)

Tags: .htaccess

i can't enable clean url. Mod_rewrite is already enabled. Anything i'm missing? here is the conf

my apache is running user mode, the document root is in /home/drupal/public_html

/etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal.domain.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias www.drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias webmail.drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias admin.drupal.domain.local
DocumentRoot /home/drupal/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/drupal.domain.local_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/drupal.domain.local_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/drupal/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/drupal/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/drupal/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All
#Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/drupal/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/drupal/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/drupal/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.drupal.domain.local
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://drupal.domain.local:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.drupal.domain.local
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://drupal.domain.local:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 7200
FcgidMaxRequestLen 2073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "drupal.domain.local statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/drupal/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias www.drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias webmail.drupal.domain.local
ServerAlias admin.drupal.domain.local
DocumentRoot /home/drupal/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/drupal.domain.local_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/drupal.domain.local_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/drupal/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/drupal/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/drupal/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/drupal/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/drupal/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/drupal/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.drupal.domain.local
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://drupal.domain.local:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.drupal.domain.local
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://drupal.domain.local:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/drupal/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/drupal/ssl.key
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "drupal.domin.local statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/drupal/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
   #
    # Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
    #
    # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
    <FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
      Order allow,deny
    </FilesMatch>


    # Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
    # Options -Indexes


    # Follow symbolic links in this directory.
    # Options +FollowSymLinks


    # Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php


    # Set the default handler.
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm


    # Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
    # sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
    # includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.


    # PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
      php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
      php_flag register_globals                 off
      php_flag session.auto_start               off
      php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
      php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
      php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
    </IfModule>


    # Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      # Enable expirations.
      ExpiresActive On


      # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
      ExpiresDefault A1209600


      <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
        # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
        # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
        # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
        # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
        ExpiresActive Off
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>


    # Various rewrite rules.
    <IfModule 

mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on


  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]


  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]


  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /


  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]


    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]


    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]


    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride All
        #AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
                Options Indexes
        #Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all granted
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's probably better to raise this with the Virtualmin community, as it's largely about Virtualmin-specific conf and apache setup. I can't see any issues with the files supplied, and you'd need to debug logs to see if there's any issues. Are you sure mod_rewrite is working? Have you tested it? Does the site work without rewrite?

Comment: i can access the website by http://drupal.domain.local/node/1 like, that, but i can't make the clean urls enable in configuration, where can i find the log?

Comment: Looks to me like your clean urls (mod_rewrite) are working fine. If it wasn't working, the url would be drupal.domain.local/?q=node/x. Perhaps you mean SEO-friendly urls. Pathauto module does that as it's not part of core. https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: I created another drupal vhost using virtualmin, using the dev version, the clean urls started with no need to enable. It is strange

Comment: It may help to remove the new lines in the htaccess file for the conditional If mod_rewrite.c

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing `Options +FollowSymLinks` in Drupal's .htaccess file worked:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

It looks like it is more secure too: http://drupal.org/node/1269780